# Straight go to "Object" view mode in AR Quicklook

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, quicklook, arquicklook

I am working on an iOS shopping app and users can see the products in AR (Quicklook - QLPreviewController). When the user opens the AR screen, the app goes to AR mode(camera) of Quicklook. Just wondering if I can update the app to straight go to "Object" view mode. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Food for thought, if you add the QLPreviewController.view as a subview and make it anything less than fullscreen, you'll see the OBJECT view.  Unfortunately the overlay buttons will not show (X to dismiss, AR and OBJECT toggle, and share button)